# Why does Velkan Valerious become a slave to Dracula but Van Helsing doesn't?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, van-helsing

In the movie Van Helsing (2004):

Velkan Valerious after bitten by a werewolf becomes a werewolf and slave to Dracula.

But Van Helsing after bitten by Velkan (in werewolf form) becomes a werewolf but won't obey Dracula!? and kill him!

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When her brother turned into a werewolf and Anna and Van Helsing tracked him to Frankenstein's castle, they realized that it was the stroke of midnight and the full moon that had caused her brother to fall completely under Dracula's control. Later, after Van Helsing becomes a werewolf, there is a race against time in the final act for Van Helsing to kill Dracula before he becomes completely a slave to him. Prior to midnight, Dracula does appear to have influence over him, but not enough to completely control him.

Check out the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Helsing_%28film%29#Plot) under Plot for a more complete account account.

Comment: Why is he having control on werewolves can you elaborate!

Comment: @praneethkumar As I understand it, in the original Dracula novels, there is a strong connection between Dracula and wolves. In some stories he can even turn into a wolf as well as a bat. In others, he uses wolves to hunt. In this movie, *Van Helsing*, they built on that mythos and allowed Dracula to control werewolves but only after using the power of the moon to completely enslave them.

Comment: You mean Dracula doesn't have much time to take Van under his control?

Comment: @praneethkumar It is more like Van doesn't have long until Dracula can completely control him. So, once Van was a werewolf, he only has a short time to kill Dracula before Dracula will control him.